# How to center a column in a row?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I was exploring a bit of bootstrap and created a simple row with a column. I set this column to size 4, so it takes up 1/3 of the row.

To center it I used the following code:

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
                <div>I am here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

However I'm getting the following result, shown in the image below:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what I am missing/doing wrong. Take you so much in advance :)

Comment: Isn't it centered one-third of the way?

Comment: `align` is for top-to-bottom, `justify` for left to right - Or to be more precise: Justify is in flow direction. So for a column it would be top to bottom. But have a look for the class documentation for grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ - comment below already has the correct answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [justify-content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) to center items within a row.

The `.row` class already displays in `flex`. Now, all you need to do is tell it how to align its children i.e. `justify-content: center`. For more on flexbox layout, see: [*A Complete Guide to Flexbox*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  border: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
      <div>I am here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could add a column right before the one in the center, but this is a hack...

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
      <div>I am here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the first option fixed it for me thank you. Could you explain to me what it did exactly?

Comment: @Dreamy I linked to the bootstrap documentation. The `.row` class is already displaying `flex`. You just need to tell it how to align its children i.e. `justify-content: center`. For more on flexbox layout, see: [_A Complete Guide to Flexbox_](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). **Note:** I adapted this comment in my response above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content-center` to center a column in a row.

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div>I am here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do that

### Old School

You need to add `offest` class

**Pattern**

```
offset-md-*
```

to be like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-4" align="center">
   <div>I am here</div>
</div>
```

### New School [Best Practice]

or by just using `justifty-content-center` like this

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
      <div>I am here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> **Notice:** it would be better to use `justifty-content-center` class instead of `offset`

you can read more about [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) and [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

Comment: Isn't a good practice to use offset to center a column in a row

Comment: @Francisco check it again i describe each of them